# Confusion regarding the definition of state of a qubit

Tags: quantum-state

I am currently reading the ["The Mathematics of Quantum Coin-Flipping"](https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=934443) by Carl A. Miller. On page 1909 (the second page in the pdf linked above) the author defines the state of a qubit as a matrix of the form

$$\phi = \begin{bmatrix} a &b \\ \overline{b} &c\end{bmatrix},$$

where $a$ and $c$ are real numbers such that $a + c = 1$ and $b$ is a complex number such that the determinant $ac-\lvert b \rvert^2 \ge 0$. In case of a measurement said qubit is $0$ with probability $a$ and $1$ with probability $c$.

However, from the lecture I only know the following (standard?) definition: A qubit is in the state $\alpha \vert 0 \rangle + \beta \vert 1 \rangle$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$, such that $\lvert\alpha\rvert^2 + \lvert \beta \rvert^2 = 1$. In case of measurement said qubit is $0$ with probability $\lvert\alpha\rvert^2$ and $1$ with probability $\lvert \beta \rvert^2$.

If I am not mistaken these definitions should be equivalent, but I do not see it. Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: The state which you are referring to (the vector) is what is known as the pure state. The state from the paper is what is known as the [density matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix). Basically, the density matrix is a weighted combination of pure states, where the weight (probability) is a classical probability, our ignorance towards the system, and not some inherent indeterminism. Try going through section 2.4 of Nielsen and Chaung or section III of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.00967.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $\phi$ you give is a [density matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) representation of a qubit which is different to the statevector form you may be used to.

As you say the state of a qubit can be represented by a statevector $|\psi\rangle$ with the following form.

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers satisfying
\begin{equation}
|\alpha|^2 +|\beta|^2=1.
\end{equation}

The density matrix (an equally valid form usually denoted by $\rho$) allows you to write statistical mixtures of states rather than just pure quantum states.

The density matrix of a pure state $|\psi\rangle$ is given by the outer product $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$.

\begin{equation}
\rho = |\psi \rangle\langle\psi| = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\bar{\alpha}& \bar{\beta} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}|\alpha|^2& \alpha\bar{\beta} \\ \beta \bar{\alpha} & |\beta|^2\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Clearly $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$ are both real numbers  so we can replace them with the new letters $a$ and $c$. This is where $a+c=1$ comes from. The diagonal entires of a density matrix correspond to probabilities so the trace must equal 1.

Also if we conjugate the product $(\alpha \bar{\beta})\,$, we get  $\beta \bar{\alpha}\,$. This means we can set $b=\alpha \bar{\beta}$.

Therefore the matrix $\rho$ above is equivalent to the matrix $\phi$ that you give with
\begin{align}
a&=|\alpha|^2, \\ b&=\alpha\bar{\beta}\,,  \\ c &= |\beta|^2\,.
\end{align}

Hope this helps.